# document.getElementById difference assigning

Tags: javascript

```
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Click to See</button>
```

When I use the id demo in " " it is showing text properly,

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').src='right_1.png'">Right</button>
```

When I use the id demo in ' ' here then it works

What is difference ?

Comment: You said both work … why do you think there is a difference? It really isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: The difference is simply that in the first code, the onclick attribute value uses single quotes as delimiters, so _inside_ the value double quotes can be used without escaping ... whereas in the second one, it is the other way around. This has nothing whatsoever to do specifically with getElementById.

Comment: In first code, if I use demo in single quote it is not working. and if I use "demo" in second code it is not working

Answer (score 1):

if you noticed `onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` , just after `"onclick="` you are using single quote (') so if you use single quote (') for 'demo' also , JS will interpret it as if you have closed the single quote (') which you have opened at the beginning , hence it will not work. So if you used single quote in the front, you need to use "" in the middle. If you have used double quotes in the front, you need to use single quote in the middle for demo. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score -1):

Both do work, and which one to use (*double-quoted or single-quoted*) is up to the **programmers** preferences.

From my understanding, you can use one quotation-format as literal, and the other one as complementary. **Javascript** as a scripting language sees a difference between the two quotations, but still makes them binary mean the same thing. This makes the quotations **not directly correlate** to each other, and hence you don't have to escape the quotes when mixing them.

It is **preferable** tough that you use the same quotations, and not mix them.

Why and how the Javascript language is built like this, I have no idea. Maybe you should mail [ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/) and ask them. I do know tough, that some languages do not see a "**difference**" between the quotation-format e.g. Python.